# What is dimensional consistency, mathematically?

Tags: physics

When going through symbolic calculations involving physical measurements, it's common to check that the final result is dimensionally consistent. (If I'm calculating a frequency, I'd better get something with units 1/s in the end.) Mathematically, where does the requirement of dimensional consistency come from?

To make this more concrete, say I have some ugly PDE describing a physical problem. After we write it down, it's just a pile of symbols; there's no longer anything indicating that $x$ is a length and $t$ is a time. How can we know a priori that dimensionally inconsistent expressions will never be valid solutions? How can I prove, in general, that the correct solution has the "right mix" of dimensional quantities?

I understand the physical reasons, and I'm familiar with using dimensional analysis, but I'm looking for a more mathematical explanation.

Comment: http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2012/12/29/a-mathematical-formalisation-of-dimensional-analysis/

Comment: Thanks for the great link! I haven't finished, but that seems to be what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Buckingham Pi Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckingham_pi_theorem).  See e.g. chapter 1 of Bluman and Anco, [Symmetry and Integration Methods for Differential Equations](http://books.google.ca/books?id=qpHv_EcjaNAC&printsec=frontcover&dq=editions%3afNA5aJFAYmAC&hl=en&sa=X&ei=cu0yUaDsDuaaiALDuoCwCA&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Answer (score 4):

You can check dimensional consistency all along.  $\sin x$ or $\exp x$ are only defined if $x$ is dimensionless.  If you take the sine or exp of some combination, it has to be dimensionless.  This is a very effective way to catch errors in a derivation.  Even if you have a dimensionless problem, it has to stay correct if you attach dimensions.  If you have the standard quadratic, $ax^2+bx+c=0$ you can just assign $x$ dimensions of length.  Then $a$ must be length$^{-2}$ and so on.  If your final result doesn't respect this, you have made an error.